# cx_freeze: ImportError: DLL load failed: This specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, import, pyqt4, cx-freeze

I developed a PyQt4 application with Python36 on one machine and successfully complied it with cx_freeze. The resulting .exe works fine on the development computer but results in the the following error when running on different Windows based computer:

> cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File 
>   "C:..\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-package\cx_Freeze\initscripts_startup_, line 12 in 
>   File
>   "C:...\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-package\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py, line 24, in  File ".py", line 17, in 
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: This specified module could not be found.

Line 17 from my code is referring to PyQt4:

> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

I assumed cx_freeze copied over all the required DLLs from my development machine so I am a bit confused. Can anyone help me make since of this error?

Comment: Just wondering if you have managed to make any progress with this issue? I believe I hit the exact same problem this week while moving a project to python 3.5. Frustratingly all of the PyQt4 dlls seem to be present in output build folder so currently slightly at a loss with it.
Someone else seems to have had the same issue here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4himd6/troubles_with_pyqt_and_cx_freeze_running_the_exe Sorry for putting this as an answer but I'm unable to leave a comment.

Comment: I have the same problem.